# HLS (.m3u8) format video from file not playing on iOS devices

Tags: ios, flutter, http-live-streaming, video-player, core-media

I'm trying to play videos offline, and this works on Android but on iOS, even when run on real device it's showing the following error:

`[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CoreMediaErrorDomain error -12865.), null, null)`

Note: Using network URL' it played fine.

I'm wondering if there's anything we missed to make these files play?